# STDOUT not resolved in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem using Eclipse and CDT, the problem started with a beginners code using **printf()** to ask for input and **scanf()** to store the input,  but the console will not display the **printf()** arguments until after it has been given the **scanf()** arguments.

I found many threads linked to this problem and understand it is a bug in eclipe and that the buffers are not being flushed properly even when using \n  . 
The solution seems to be either use **fflush(stdout)** after each **printf()** or to add **setbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)** at the beginning of the **main()** function.

I added the **setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)** i also tried **fflush(stdout)** but eclipse is saying stdout can not be resolved.

Can anyone please tell say why and how to fix this.

Thank you.

Mick Caulton

This Is My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 

//setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

char letter; 
int num1,num2;

printf("Enter any one keyboard character:\n");
// fflush(stdout);
scanf("%c",&letter);

printf("Enter 2 integers separated by a space: \n");
//fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);

printf("Numbers input: %d and %d\n",num1,num2);
printf("Letter input: %c",letter);
printf(" stored at %p \n",&letter); 

return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you produce a minimal source that still exhibits this behaviour? TBH it looks like you just didn't `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have included the stdio library - one of the first things i checked. I will post you my code below. As it is when run the console of eclipse stays blank. When you enter the required input ( letter and two numbers followed by return) it then prints out everything. the request and the confirmation. The commented out lines are the solutions i found online to flush the stdout buffer which everyone seems to say is the work around, but as i said before Eclipse is telling me stdout can not be resolved. Thank you Again.

Comment: 'code'
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
//setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
char letter;
int num1,num2;
printf("Enter any one keyboard character:\n");
// fflush(stdout);
scanf("%c",&letter);
printf("Enter 2 integers separated by a space: \n");
//fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
printf("Numbers input: %d and %d\n",num1,num2);
printf("Letter input: %c",letter);
printf(" stored at %p \n",&letter);
return 0;
}

Comment: 'code''code' #include <stdio.h> int main(){ //setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); char letter; int num1,num2; printf("Enter any one keyboard character:\n"); // fflush(stdout); scanf("%c",&letter); printf("Enter 2 integers separated by a space: \n"); //fflush(stdout); scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2); printf("Numbers input: %d and %d\n",num1,num2); printf("Letter input: %c",letter); printf(" stored at %p \n",&letter); return 0; }'code'

Comment: oops trying to work out the formating on here how do i post the code propperly ?

Comment: Ok Sorry about that i have now added my code to an edited version of the question. Again my apologies and thanks.

Comment: Thank you again and i have now amended the main question to include the code. I hope this makes it clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on Windows, keep in mind that the End-Of-Line indicator is `\r\n` (you're using just `\n`), and the Eclipse console window famously only does whole lines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Unfortunately it does not address the issues i have. As to your comment about windows using the \r\n escape sequence as opposed to  \n like linux, i just tried it to see if it made any noticeable difference, i cant say i see any difference in the output through the eclipse console. If i have miss understood  you i am sorry. If you are able to help me amend work out how to make the above code work as intended please leave another comment. Thank you again.